# Reusing Component State issue - State always retained for last reference loaded

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-functional-component

I tried creating a reusable component in React. Which has a textInput and secure text entry handled in the state of the reusable component. **But the state is not getting maintained differently when reusing always the last state is updated,**

Issue: If i call the reusable const two times on a single screen or on the next screen in stack. The toggle for secure entry keeps changing for the last field loaded and earlier loaded fields state is lost.
**i.e., when i click on toggle of Password, text change from hidden to visible or vice-versa happens for Confirm password field.**

This is how i call

```
<View style={styles.inputContainerView}>
                    <InputTextFieldView
                        enteredText={passwordEntered}
                        setEnteredText={setPasswordEntered}
                        title={Constants.registerPasswordPlaceholder} icon={lockIcon}
                        isSecureEntry={true}
                        placeholder={Constants.registerPasswordPlaceholder} />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.inputContainerView}>
                    <InputTextFieldView
                        enteredText={confirmPasswordEntered}
                        setEnteredText={setConfirmPasswordEntered}
                        title={Constants.registerConfirmPasswordPlaceholder} icon={lockIcon}
                        isSecureEntry={true}
                        placeholder={Constants.registerConfirmPasswordPlaceholder} />
                </View>
```

My component:

```
const InputTextFieldView = ({ enteredText, setEnteredText, title, icon, isSecureEntry, placeholder }) => {

const [isSecureEntryEnabled, setIsSecureEntryEnabled] = useState(isSecureEntry)
const eyeOpenIcon = require('../../../assets/visibility.png')
const eyeCloseIcon = require('../../../assets/close-eye.png')

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('called')
}, [])

toggleSecureTextEntry = () => {
    console.log('title', title)
    setIsSecureEntryEnabled(!isSecureEntryEnabled)
}

return (
    <View style={styles.fieldsContainerView}>
        <Text style={styles.titleStyle}>{title}</Text>
        <View style={[styles.fieldInputContainerView, {padding: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 12 : 0}]}>
            <Image source={icon} style={styles.fieldIconView} />
            <TextInput secureTextEntry={isSecureEntryEnabled} style={{ width: isSecureEntry ? '75%' : '85%' }} onChange={() => setEnteredText()} value={enteredText} placeholder={placeholder} />
            {isSecureEntry &&
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => toggleSecureTextEntry()}>
                    <Image source={isSecureEntryEnabled ? eyeOpenIcon : eyeCloseIcon} style={styles.fieldIconView} />
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            }
        </View>
    </View>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was happening due to `TouchableWithoutFeedback`. Now used `TouchableOpacity` and it started to work. Not sure why but it may help someone

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you are using `isSecureEntry` as the hook to toggle the password fields? If so, it looks like you are passing the same state to both
the password field and the confirm password field. Right now, you essentially have one light switch that controls two different lamps. So you are going to want to have separate separate useState hooks for the password field and confirm password field. Then pass each one to the correct component.

```js
const [passwordSecure, togglePasswordSecure] = useState(true);
const [confirmPasswordSecure, toggleConfirmPasswordSecure] = useState(true);

const togglePasswordField = () => {
  togglePasswordSecure(!passwordSecure)
  };
  
 const toggleConfirmPasswordField = () => {
  toggleConfirmPasswordSecure(!confirmPasswordSecure)
  };
```

Comment: So, it will not be completely reusable  and this needs to be added in Input Component or parent?

Comment: Okay,  There's an issue. When i try it always returns ref of last rendered.

Comment: @JatinGarg Sorry I updated the code in my answer. You should use a Boolean value to initialize the usestate hook. So if you want the password to be secure initially use 'true' otherwise use false.